# What kinds of semiconductors are used for high voltage devices?

Tags: high-voltage, semiconductors

IIRC, gallium nitride is one of them. But what about silicon? What do they use for making thyristor valves found in High Voltage Direct Current power stations?

Comment: Silicon carbide is sometimes used, I believe. I know there's one professor at my university researching it.

Comment: Additionally, silicon nitride is an insulator. I believe it's sometimes used instead of the oxide for MOS processes. (would that make it a MNS process?)

Answer (score 0):

Most high-voltage devices are still silicon.  It is only recently that other types of semiconductor are being used.